# Is it possible to write an Eslint plugin to check if a required file exist?

Tags: javascript, plugins, eslint

We use Eslint to check our javascript projects, it works great, but we have some special requirements like checking if a required file existed or not, e.g. `.gitignore`.

I tried to write a custom eslint plugin, but can't get an idea: seems like eslint can only check the AST of the code, but not the files themselves.

Does eslint provide any API that I can get all the files of the project and I can have a check?

Answer (score 2):

No, ESLint doesn't provide any APIs dealing with files. ESLint is JavaScript static analysis tool, and as such doesn't really deal with file system. However, ESLint rules are just JavaScript, so you can execute arbitrary code in it. You can take a look at [eslint-plugin-import](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import) which already does what you are looking for.